# Remove the counts on selection of the list in the Multi-select list using Antd (Ant -design) React js

Tags: reactjs, antd

The total count of the keys are present in the list . Onclick of the lists I need to display only the names and not the numbers . How do I remove the numbers and just display the clicked list . 
Note : I need the count in the list display

```
const Option = Select.Option; 
const children = [];
const pubTypes = [
  { key: "Webcasts", count: 200 },
  { key: "Review", count: 300 },
  { key: "Portrait", count: 500 }
];
pubTypes.map(element =>
  children.push(
    <Select.Option key={element.key}>
      {element.key} ({element.count})
    </Select.Option>
  )
);

class UserRemoteSelect extends React.Component {
  handleChange = value => {
    console.log(`selected ${value}`);
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <Select
        mode="multiple"
        style={{ width: "100%" }}
        placeholder="Please select"
        onChange={this.handleChange}
      >
        {children}
      </Select>
    );
  }
}
```

[Follow the link for more description]

https://codesandbox.io/s/w2pl8r0xyw

Answer (score 0):

You can set labelInValue: false to achieve this.

Comment: could you elaborate I could not get the desired output